# BackboneJs unable to render template in rendered template

Tags: templates, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have two views and I want to render a second one inside the first one. 
I am doing this:

First view:

```
var EventContainer = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#sectionContainer',
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get('templates/home/eventContainer.html', function(data) {
        that.template = _.template(data, {}); //Option to pass any dynamic values to template
        $(that.el).append(that.template); //adding the template content to the main template.
    }, 'html');

    new EventList();

    return this;
  }
});
```

Template for the first view:

```
<div class="main-content pull-left">
    <ul id="eventList" class="event-list no-list-style no-padding"> </ul>
</div>
```

Second view:

```
var EventList = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#eventList',
  initialize: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.EventsCollection = new EventsCollection();
    this.EventsCollection.fetch({
        success: function(data) {
            that.collection = data;
            that.setTemplate();
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
  },
  setTemplate: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get('templates/home/eventList.html', function(data) {
        that.template = _.template(data);
        that.render();
    }, 'html');
  },
  render: function() {
    var that = this;

    this.collection.each(function(eventData) {
        var eventTemplate = that.template(eventData.toJSON());
        console.log('---> ' + $(that.el));
        $(that.el).append(eventTemplate);
    });

    return this;

  }
});
```

Template for the second View:

```
<li class="event-item">
    <small><%= like_count%> </small>
</li>
```

When I try to render the second view, *el* is undefined.

What m I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently if I use 

`$('#eventList').append(eventTemplate);`

instead of 

`$(that.el).append(eventTemplate);`

It work, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at `this.el` inside `EventList#initialize`, I think you'll find that it is `undefined` rather than the `<ul>` that you're expecting it to be. Why would that be? Where does `#eventList` come from? `#eventList` comes from `EventContainer`'s template and that won't be in the DOM until this AJAX call:

```
$.get('templates/home/eventContainer.html', ...)
```

completes. That `$.get` won't complete until well after your `new EventList();`. When you instantiate your `EventList`, it will go looking for `#eventList` but won't find anything, that will leave you with `this.el` being `undefined`. Then later on, that `$.get` will return and `#eventList` will show up in the DOM; this is why `$('#eventList')` works.

The easy solution is to defer instantiating your `EventList` until after you've added the necessary things to the DOM:

```
$.get('templates/home/eventContainer.html', function(data) {
    that.template = _.template(data, {});
    $(that.el).append(that.template);
    new EventList(); // <-----------------------
}, 'html');
```

If you're going to do this, then you could make the dependency explicit by dropping the `el` from the `EventList` definition and specifying it when you create the view instead:

```
$.get('templates/home/eventContainer.html', function(data) {
    that.template = _.template(data, {});
    $(that.el).append(that.template);
    new EventList({ el: that.$('#eventList') });
}, 'html');
```

Comment: Amazing explanation! Thank you so much! 
Worked! 5starts! Thanks!